# Unable to resubmit in-app purchase for review

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

My in-app purchase was rejected with the explanation:

```
Your in-app purchase has been returned. 
Fix the marked items and submit it again. 
For more information, see the Notes from App Review.
```

and in the notes it says:

```
We have returned your in-app purchase products to you as the required
binary was not submitted. When you are ready to submit the binary,     
please resubmit the in-app purchase products with the binary.
```

Not sure what this means, but I have submitted a new binary.
Still, while the binary is in "Waiting for review", the in-app purchase's status remains "Developer Action Needed".

But there isn't any "Submit" button for in-app purchase. What should I do next?

Thank you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I faced the exact same issue. There is no clear way to resubmit them once they are rejected, there is also no way to submit a build with you IAP products. (This might be fixed in the future)

This is how I was able to get them approved:

1- In iTunes connect go to: Features -> In-App purchases and open the product that you want to submit. For me the status was "Developer action required". Once you open it, make some changes to the Localizations section and save the the IAP product, this should change the status from "Developer action needed" to "Waiting for review". You can revert the changes you made. (This step was suggested to me by apple)

2- The second step is getting them to review the IAP subscriptions with the build you submit. Again there was no way for me to do so. So what I ended up doing is leaving a note in the "App Reviewer Information" section to please review the in app purchases

Comment: You are a star! After lots of rejection I came to this answer and 2nd point worked for me and you literally saved me. Thanks a ton!

Comment: I can't believe this is still a thing in 2023. Apple just could not care less about its developers - everything is a chore.
(Thanks BTW)

Answer (score 0):

Also you can:
1)add any new localization,
2)then delete previous,
3)then delete new one
4)and create first one more time.
It will change automatically to "waiting for review".

Also I write on notes, to check my IAP